# How to retrieve MongoDB documents via selection by array field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

My data structure is as follows:

```
{
    _id: ...,
    topLevelField: ...,
    items: [{
        field1: ...,
        field2: ...
    }]
}
```

I want to query all documents where `topLevelField = 'X'` **OR** `items` array contains an object with `field2 = 'Y'`.

**Is this possible in Meteor?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm providing the mongo query, I don't think it'll be difficult for you to send it via Meteor (which I don't use).

So try this simple [$or](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) query

```
{ $or: [ { 'topLevelField' : 'X' }, { 'items.field2' : 'Y' } ] }
```